# BBBBBBBBBB -> BB

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**I'm trying to tell you something. Can you tell me what it is?**

---

[image]

---

Good luck!

Comment: rot13( Qbrf gur gvgyr ersre gb punatvat ahzoref va onfr gra gb onfr gjb? )

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Yes, that's what it refers to

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are

> wishing us a **HAPPY NEW YEAR**!

> By writing the numbers on the right in base 2, using black for 1 and white for 0, we get:
>  [image: binary dots]

We are then able to read:

> [image: happy new year!]

> Thank you very much! Wishing everyone the best for 2024!

Comment: Well done! Cheers to that, happy new year!

Comment: Nice one!! Btw I think the 12 rows here might be an Easter egg for hinting at the 12 months of the year